# addEventListener method not being added in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, listener, actionlistener, onclicklistener

I have a function `addListeners()` in my script, which takes a string argument (say `arg`) and adds action listeners on buttons with ids `arg+"Del"` and `arg+"Edit"`; for ex: if `arg="abc"`, it would add action listeners to buttons with ids `abcDel` and `abcEdit`. Also, there exists a method `confirmEditTask()` which edits the task name (a string with which the two buttons are placed) and changes the ids of the two buttons which are the task name concatenated with `"Del"` and `"Edit"` depending on the button. After changing their ids, it calls `addListeners()` again and passes the new task name as its string argument so that it adds the action listeners again. However, I see that the ids are being changed; **however the action listeners are not being added again**, though they were added initially (before changing their ids) (I checked in the 'Elements' tag of the browser). I've displayed the codes of the two functions below.

```
function addListeners(arg){
    document.getElementById(arg+"Del").addEventListener("click",function(){

        ...some code...
    });
    document.getElementById(arg+"Edit").addEventListener("click",function(){
        ...some code...
    });
}
function confirmEditTask(initArg,arg){

    var scopeANG=angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="taskShower"]')).scope();
    for(i=0;i<scopeANG.tasks.length;i++){
        if(scopeANG.tasks[i].valueOf()===initArg.valueOf()){

            scopeANG.tasks[i]=arg;
            document.getElementById(initArg+"Del").id=arg+"Del";
            document.getElementById(initArg+"Edit").id=arg+"Edit";
            addListeners(arg);
            console.log(scopeANG.tasks);
            editTaskFlag=false;
            scopeANG.$apply();
            return;
        }
    }

    scopeANG.$apply();
}
```

Comment: Changing an element's ID does not remove event handlers, the original ones are still there. This may cause issues if you attach new handlers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - However, I cannot see any click listener (not even the original ones) on the button